# parallel sum reduction implementation in opencl

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am going through the sample code of NVIDIA provided at [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl#oclReduction)

In the sample kernels code (file `oclReduction_kernel.c`) reduce4 uses the technique of

1) unrolling and removing synchronization barrier for thread id < 32.

2) Apart from this the code uses the blockSize checks to sum the data in local memory. I think there in OpenCL we have `get_local_size(0/1)` to know the work group size. Block Size is confusing me.

I am not able to understand both the points mentioned above. Why and how these  things helping out in optimization? Any explanation on reduce5 and reduce6 will be helpful as well.

Comment: The presentation at https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf refers to CUDA (and admittedly, I think that the OpenCL samples have basically been created by converting the CUDA kernels to OpenCL as literally as possible), but it might bring some insights, particularly regarding the further optimized reduce5/reduce6 versions.

Comment: Yes they were in cuda only. But it doesn't answer any queries

Comment: Thanks @Marco13 I missed ur link in my night time. May be I was sleepy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that pretty much explained in slide 21 and 22 of https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf which @Marco13 linked in comments.

> - As reduction proceeds, # “active” threads decreases
> - - When s <= 32, we have only one warp left
> - Instructions are SIMD synchronous within a  warp.
> - That means when s <= 32:
> - - We don’t need to __syncthreads()
> - - We don’t need “if (tid < s)” because it doesn’t save any work
>
> Without unrolling, all warps execute every iteration of the for loop
> and if statement

And by https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a5.htm:

> The code is actually executed in groups of 32 threads, what NVIDIA
> calls a warp.
>
> Each core can execute a sequential thread, but the cores execute in
> what NVIDIA calls SIMT (Single Instruction, Multiple Thread) fashion;
> all cores in the same group execute the same instruction at the same
> time, much like classical SIMD processors.

Re 2) `blockSize` there looks to be size of the work group.

Comment: When we say the code is SIMD-4 compiled for GPU. Is it correct to say that:: There will be four SIMD cores which will be executing the same instruction and the instruction can be like float/float4/float16 ??